# One caveat: Know when passengers must be back on board the plane

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> One caveat: Know when passengers must be back on board **the plane**.

I find this sentence really weird. It's [an example sentence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/caveat) explaining the word "caveat". I couldn't get what "the plane" does there.

> Know when passengers must be back (why?) **to board the plane**.
>
> Know when passengers must be back (where?) **onto the board of the plane**.

Unlike these versions, the original one doesn't make sense to me. Is it a typo or is there any semantic or grammatical point I failed to notice?

EDIT:

I suppose *on board* is a prepositional phrase used as an adverb here. How can a phrase answering the "where" question can be followed by a noun without any prepositions between them (as in "the board **of** the plane")

Comment: Your second sentence is wrong. "on board of the plane" isn't standard English.

Comment: @pboss3010 yes, I understand it. I was trying to make sense out of it and suggested alternatives which might explain why I am struggling with the original sentence. Would "to/onto the board of the plane" work?

Comment: the phrase is "on board the [vehicle]", I don't know where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: It's not ***the*** *board* ***of*** *the plane*. It's simply ***on board*** *the plane*. You need to stop adding an article, breaking up the expression, and treating *board* is a noun. ***On board*** is a synonym for [***aboard***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aboard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly grammatical. Compare:

> While on board the plane, please don't use your cell phone.

I assume you'd be happier with this sentence, right?

> One caveat: Know when passengers must be back on the plane.

In fact, **back on board the plane** is just like **back on the plane**, a prepositional phrase. The syntax tree would look something like this (I will wait for BillJ to critique my diagram):

[image]

The prepositional phrase (PP) **on board** is part of a longer PP **back on board the plane** and functions similarly to preposition **on**. The whole PP **back on board the plane** in turn functions as a nominal (predicative).

You seem to be having issues with the lack of a preposition between "board" and "the plane". "On board" is a set phrase, so it is no longer "the board of the plane".